# Differences in scrolling when using headless

Tags: python, selenium, scroll, web-crawler

It is crawling after infinite scrolling using selenium, but if `headless` is not used for chromeoption, it goes down to the bottom. But if use `headless` cut off in the middle. Why do I get an error when using headless?

```
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
last_height = 0
while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
            break
    last_height = new_height
        time.sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is your windowssize property

make sure window-size property and non headless resolution are the same:

> --window-size=1980,1030

Also use :

```
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.clientHeight)
```

[Source](https://thisthat.dev/client-height-vs-offset-height-vs-scroll-height)

> clientHeight = the height of an element + the vertical padding.

> offsetHeight = the height of the element + the vertical padding + the
> top and bottom borders + the horizontal scrollbar (if it's available).

> scrollHeight = the height of element's content (including the content
> which isn't visible on the screen) + the vertical padding.

Comment: I did --window-size=1980,1030 and it seems to be resolved. Thank you for answer