# Infinite scroll not working in headless mode with Python, Selenium and Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, screen-scraping, google-chrome-headless

I have the following script, which works ok to to scroll to the bottom of the page. It works when I don't use the `--headless` option. However, the infinite scroll does not work once I have introduced that.
Here is my current script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotInteractableException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = 'https://www.vivino.com/explore?e=eJzLLbI11rNQy83MszU0UMtNrLA1NFJLrrQNDVZLBhIuagW2hmrpabZliUWZqSWJOWr5RSm2avlJlbZq5SXRsUDJYtu8SgD3XBY4'
# Specify the path to Chrome binary file
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome Beta\Application\chrome.exe'
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=OFF")
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")


# Create a new Chrome webdriver instance
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options, service = Service("chromedriver.exe"))

# Load the initial URL
driver.get(url)


time.sleep(10)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 10

count = 0
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    count = count + 1
    print(count, ' scrolls')

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

# Save soup to local html file
with open('headless.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(soup.prettify())

driver.quit()
```

I have tried a few things:

1. Adding `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')` and alternatively `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')`
2. I even added these two:

   `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`

   `chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor")`

Still to no avail. I added the `--start-maximized` option because i noticed that even with the regular visible browser, the div that has the infinite scrolling part titled `explore-page-app` has to be visible  in the window otherwise if i just go to the end of the page and it is not visible no new result will load in the listings.

So is there anyway I can make infinite scrolling work in headless mode?

Comment: Produce [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What do you mean by `"infinite scroll does not work"`? What is the output when the headless mode is used? It still creates the HTML file when the headless mode is used.

Comment: @Bibhav  the code i sent is easily reproducible. If you run that code without the headless option, it will scroll 8 times as expected to reach the end. If you run it with the headless tag, it does not scroll, that is what is meant by infinite scroll is not working in headless mode.

Comment: @Bibhav that happens when you run it as it is. You have to comment out the line that says `chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')` also, if you browser does not start maximized by default, as i mentioned in the original post, you will have to add the `chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differences in scrolling when using headless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715299/differences-in-scrolling-when-using-headless)